# Alarm manager not working for multiple Alarm in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want to use alarm based on some database time value . Currently my alarm is working for one alarm Like : I have 3 alarm set at 8:30am , 10:20am and 12:20Pm
my alarm is working only for one value .This is reminder class there i am creating the alarm

```
public class OwnGoalReminder extends EventReminder {
    GoalOwn goalOwn;
    int interValTime;
    int goalId;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int requestCode;
    String type;

    public void setInterValTime(int interValTime) {
        this.interValTime = interValTime;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }
    public void setRequestCode(int requestCode) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }
    @Override
    protected int getGoalId(){return this.goalId;}

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    public OwnGoalReminder(Context context , int goalId, int interValTime){
        super(context);
        this.interValTime = interValTime;
        this.goalId = goalId;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }


    @Override
    protected String getMessage() {
        return "Reminder!!! You should check your goals!";
    }

    @Override
    protected int getRequestCode() {
        return requestCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected EventTime getEventTime() {
        int h = hour;
        int m = minute;
        return new EventTime(hour,minute,interValTime);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class getBroadcastReceiver() {
        return MyBroadcastReceiver.class;
    }
}
```

This is base class of OwnGOalReminder

```
public abstract class EventReminder{
    protected Context context;
    protected Alarm alarm;
    PushNotificationsManager notificationsManager;


    public void remind() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("type", getType());
        bundle.putString("msg", getMessage());
        notificationsManager.sendNotification(bundle);
    }

    protected abstract String getType();

    protected abstract String getMessage();

    protected abstract int getRequestCode();
    protected abstract int getGoalId();

    protected abstract EventTime getEventTime();

    protected abstract Class getBroadcastReceiver();

    protected EventReminder(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        alarm = new Alarm(context, getBroadcastReceiver());
        notificationsManager = new PushNotificationsManager(context);
    }

    public void startReminder(){
        alarm.startAlert(getRequestCode(), getGoalId(), getEventTime().hour, getEventTime().minute, getEventTime().intervalInMinute);
        //alarm.setAlarm(context, getEventTime().hour, getEventTime().minute);
    }


    protected class EventTime{
        int hour, minute, intervalInMinute;
        public EventTime(int hour, int minute, int intervalInMinute){
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
            this.intervalInMinute = intervalInMinute;
        }
    }
}
```

this is alarm class there i am creating the alarmmanager

```
public class Alarm{

    private final Context context;
    private Class broadcastReceiver;

    public Alarm(Context context, Class broadcastReceiver){
        this.context = context;
        this.broadcastReceiver = broadcastReceiver;
    }

    public void startAlert(int requestCode, int gid, int hour, int minute, int intervalMinute) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "starting alert");
        int i = 10;
        Long timeToMilliSeconds = timeToMilliSeconds(hour, minute);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("reqcode", requestCode);
        intent.putExtra("time", timeToMilliSeconds);
        intent.putExtra("gid" , gid);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToMilliSeconds+
                + (i * 1000), 1000*60*intervalMinute, pendingIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @NonNull
    public static long timeToMilliSeconds(int hour, int minute) {
        Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_now.setTime(dat);
        cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);//set the alarm time
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        if(cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
            cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        }
        return cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis();
    }

}
```

This is the method here i am creating the multiple alarm object based on database value

```
public static void registerAlarm(Context context){
        if(!UserPreferences.isAlarmRegistered(context)) {
            GoalReminder goalReminder = new GoalReminder(context);


            AppraisalReminder appraisalReminder = new AppraisalReminder(context);
            goalReminder.startReminder();
            appraisalReminder.startReminder();
           // ownGoalReminder.startReminder();
            //UserPreferences.setIsAlarmRegistered(context,true);
            ArrayList<Goal> LIST_OF_OWN_GOALS = new ArrayList<>();

            LIST_OF_OWN_GOALS = (ArrayList<Goal>) Goal.getGoalFromOwnGoals();

            for (Goal g : LIST_OF_OWN_GOALS) {
                OwnGoalReminder ownGoalReminder = new OwnGoalReminder(context , g.getgId(),3 );
                int h = Integer.parseInt(g.getrTime())/60;
                int min = Integer.parseInt(g.getrTime())%60;
                ownGoalReminder.setHour(h);
                ownGoalReminder.setMinute(min);
                ownGoalReminder.setRequestCode(16);

                ownGoalReminder.setType("16");
                ownGoalReminder.startReminder();
                LIST_OF_OWN_REMINDERS.add(ownGoalReminder);

            }



        }
    }
```

This is my Broadcast receiver class :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String[] goalMessagesArray = ApraiseApplication.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goals_messages);
    private static Queue<String> goalMessagesQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(goalMessagesArray));


    private static final String[] appraisalsMessagesArray = ApraiseApplication.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.appraisals_messages);
    private static Queue<String> appraisalsMessagesQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(appraisalsMessagesArray));

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "notify");
        PushNotificationsManager notificationsManager = new PushNotificationsManager(context);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = acquireWakeLock(context);

        int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",1);
        int gId = intent.getIntExtra("gid",1);

        long time = intent.getLongExtra("time",0);
        String message = "";

        // it will create the instance of Random class
          Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        // it will generate a random number based on  goal message arrayList length
        int indexForGoalMessage = randomGenerator.nextInt(goalMessagesArray.length);

        // it will generate a random number based on  appraisalsMessagesArray length
        int indexForAppraisalsMessage = randomGenerator.nextInt(goalMessagesArray.length);
        String gid = "";


        if(isNotifyTimePassed(time)){
            //return;
        }


        if(requestCode == 123){

//           if(goalMessagesQueue.isEmpty()){
//                goalMessagesQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(goalMessagesArray));
//            }
//            message = goalMessagesQueue.poll();

            message = goalMessagesArray[indexForGoalMessage];



        }else if(requestCode == 124){

//            if(appraisalsMessagesQueue.isEmpty()){
//                appraisalsMessagesQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(appraisalsMessagesArray));
//            }
//            message = appraisalsMessagesQueue.poll();

            message = appraisalsMessagesArray[indexForAppraisalsMessage];


        }

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", Integer.toString(requestCode));
            bundle.putString("msg", message);
            bundle.putString("gid" , String.valueOf(gId));
            notificationsManager.sendNotification(bundle);

             wl.release();
    }

    @NonNull
    private PowerManager.WakeLock acquireWakeLock(Context context) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
        return wl;
    }

    private boolean isNotifyTimePassed(long time) {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis()-time) > 1000L*60L*5L;
    }

}
```

Comment: AtomicInteger can be used too to get unique id, if you are facing any issues with the ordering of notifications if there are multiple at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have found this solution from searching google ]

I have solved that problem by passing unique id which is depend on current time:-

```
final int intent_id= (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); 

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, intent_id , intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is good to set your **event id** (unique id) as the request code of PendingIntent.getBroadcast() method. So the advantage here is when you update/edit the event then alarm wont duplicate.